# Flutter android: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I installed Flutter, android studio, java, and created environment variable and android virtual machine. I created my firt app and got the error bellow when run command **flutter run**
please help me how to fix this issue.
Thank you!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2e4ba9c6fb499ccd4e81420543783cc7267ae406.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2e4ba9c6fb499ccd4e81420543783cc7267ae406.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2e4ba9c6fb499ccd4e81420543783cc7267ae406.
         > Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2e4ba9c6fb499ccd4e81420543783cc7267ae406/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2e4ba9c6fb499ccd4e81420543783cc7267ae406.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I try to uninstalled and reinstalled flutter and android studio but the issue was not solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade kotlin version. Please check project level gradle.
Please check latest kotlin version and gradle version.